# I have to hold the @ or ' for 1 second before it responds Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

Pretty simple and very confusing. In order to get the @ to respond I have to hold it down for 1 second before anything happens and then delete all of the extra characters that have been typed. same goes ' obviously. It has nothing to do with shift.

I thought maybe it was my keyboard so I tried a different keyboard and the same problem and my keyboard in a different computer without any problems. This is hugely upsetting whilst trying to program anything..

Any ideas then?

Comment: What happens if you just press it once and let go?

Comment: I assume `@` and `'` are on the same key? Why do you say "same goes for ' obviously"? If they're *not* on the same key, does the non-shifted character on each of those keys work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers for the answers dudes.

So i didn't have any other languages set but i went to 'Advanced Key Settings' ¬ Hot Keys for input languages ¬ action - Between input languages ¬ and the option 'Grave Accent (') was selected so i changed that to Not Assigned and it seemed to sort out my problem.

No idea

Answer (score 3):

You may have international keyboard where some keys are actually "[dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)". Those keys are meant to be combined with some other keys to produce new keys. Example: type ', then type e, and you should get é. You have two solutions

1. Switch to more appropriate keyboard. I always use English U.S. for programming, even if keyboard is some other type. It's just easier to remember where all important keys are.
2. After typing ' always type one space. Dead key ' + Space = live key '.

Answer (score 1):

Check the keyboard "Repeat delay" in the Control Panel.  Its likely set too high, try decreasing the delay time.